# Mounting dropbox as a network drive and running a batch file on it

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-11

I have Dropbox set as a network drive drive letter X: with all my channel logos and EPG Data Generator program and scripts for creating an XML EPG File for Tivimate. This drive also has the XML EPG File created by the EPG Data Generator Program. All works flawlessly if I click on the icon I created to run the process manually.

What I would like to do is use Windows Scheduler to run a Windows batch file to run the EPG Data Generator Program automatically from the X: drive which is where the program resides. How would I write the Windows batch file to execute this process?

I am currently unable to figure out how to do please help!

Comment: Do you already have a .exe file that does this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows task scheduler runs as system and does not know about your specific user mounted drives at runtime. As such, you need to make a script to mount the dropbox directory from a specific users profile to X: before running your scripts. You will also need admin privileges to access this path. This can be accomplished by doing something similar to the following:

*mountdrive.bat*

```
@echo off
net use x: /delete /y
net use x: \\localhost\c$\Users\Thomas\Dropbox
X:
cd "x:\my\exe\path\"
.\epgprogram.exe
```

Comment: So, on the last two lines change that to the executable directory, and the last line change to the Windows batch file on X: drive aka my Dropbox drive. Would I be able to use Windows Scheduler to run the whole process automatically?

Comment: I just created a Windows batch file using the example above ran the batch file and was able to successfully link to X: Drive aka Dropbox drive to run my EPG Updater program and create an updated XML EPG File for Tivimate.

Comment: @ThomasStevens I am glad it pointed you in the right direction. Please mark as the answer to help future viewers resolve their similar issues if this was a sufficient solution.

Comment: How do I mark the answer to help? Since this answer was the resolution to my problem.

Comment: @ThomasStevens should be a big check mark next to the response above,